# FTP SYST answer "Unix Type: L8"

Tags: unix, ftp

I am working with some form of an FTP-Server right now, and I noticed that the response of the SYST command is "Unix Type: L8". I wanted to know what exactly this means, and found out that in [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959%20%22RFC%20959) the SYST command is defined to return the type of operating system of the server as first word of its response. That still does not tell me what "Type: L8" means. I really want to know what it means though, since so many FTP-Servers out there seem to give this same response.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know where it's specified, but it indicates that the server accepts the `TYPE L` command with parameter `8`.

`TYPE L` is like `TYPE I` (binary) but comes with a parameter indicating how many bits are in a byte. When FTP was designed, 8-bit bytes weren't as universal as they are now. Section 3.1.1.4 of the same RFC covers `TYPE L` and gives some examples. (It leaves a lot unspecified though.)

There's no need for `TYPE L` any more. If you implement `TYPE I` in a client, you've done all you need to do. Servers are required to implement `TYPE A` as the default mode, but don't put too much work into that one either, since reasonable clients won't use it. (just do `\n` -> `\r\n` on sending and the inverse on receiving).

In djb's ["FTP in practice" documentation](https://cr.yp.to/ftp.html) he writes:

> Many clients misuse SYST as a declaration of server features. Some clients behave in rather strange ways when they see particular strings in the SYST response. Some clients disable essential features when they do not see particular strings in the SYST response; this poses a serious problem for servers. I recommend that all new servers respond to SYST with the meaningless string
>
> ```
> 215 UNIX Type: L8
> ```
>
> exactly as used by the majority of current servers.

Sounds like good advice to me. If you're a server you should say `UNIX Type: L8` which means "Yes, I'm an FTP server", and if you're a client, you shouldn't bother with the `SYST` command because the response tells you nothing.

Comment: Just found this post ;) - According to [this RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-ftpext-utf-8-option-00#section-2) It seems that it has something to do with `UTF-8` support. - But at least, i found some Server which send `L8` and answer in `ASCII` seems some dudes doesn't found this RFC ;)

Comment: If you're after server features, as a suggested improper use of `SYST`, then you'll want to look into `HELP SITE` command, which replies with code `214` and a list of features that FTP server supports.